# XHR and All elements?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

How to make this script catch all the elements of `<a>` and not like now with the `link-fade` class.

I have one more question. How to make this script send a request to the server via XHR and not like it does now via `location.href = link.href;`.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains("link-fade")) return;
  event.preventDefault();
  var link = event.target;
  document.body.style.opacity = 0;
  document.body.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    location.href = link.href;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
 if (!event.target.tagName !== 'A') return; // check the tag name
 event.preventDefault();
 var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
 oReq.addEventListener("load", function() {
 console.log(this.responseText());
  });
 oReq.open("GET", event.target.href);
 oReq.send();
});
```

Comment: It is possible to run the link with XHR?

Comment: And you delete the animation.

Comment: I haven't had time to thoroughly test this code before, but it doesn't catch the target `a`